# rqt saving configuration

Tags: ros, rqt-gui, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I just discovered rqt which seems to be super cool thing :) Is there a way to save configuration? So next time I just load all the plugins I've chosen previosly? (Like loading config in RViz)

Cheers,
da-na

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/65566/rqt-saving-configuration/) by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on ROS Answers with karma: 306 on 2013-06-19

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To compensate for @felix k's answer, `rqt` saves so-called `perspective` when it's run on `rqt_gui` and closed. (I just found that it's not documented) things that are saved include:

- plugins opened
- plugins' size and positions within the container window (`rqt_gui`)
- `rqt_gui`'s size and position with respect to the computer's desktop

To run `rqt_gui`, you just run:

```
$ rqt  (Groovy and later)
$ rosrun rqt_gui rqt_gui  (Fuerte)
```

Running `rqt_gui` is the recommended usage of `rqt`, although you can run each `rqt` plugin individually.

In response to the `RViz` example in your question, `rqt_gui` does NOT save the configuration of each plugins as I listed above; instead it's up to how each plugin is implemented. And the feature of `rqt` variant of `Rviz`, rqt_rviz, is the same with what `RViz` has, because `rqt_rviz` embeds `RViz`, which doesn't save the `.config` file that was used the last time (if I remember correctly). You can open an enhancement request [here](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/issues).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [da-na](https://answers.ros.org/users/4159/da-na/) on 2013-06-20**:
thank you IsaacSaito for your detailed answer :)

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-06-22**:
Actually every plugin can save its intrinsic state and restore it again. Some plugins store things like checked checkboxes and values of input fields. rqt_publisher e.g. restores the list of message types to be published to reuse the once setup publishers.

**Comment by [cshannon](https://answers.ros.org/users/24410/cshannon/) on 2015-10-11**:
Hi Dirk. Would you be able to briefly describe the procedure for saving the intrinsic state (specifically the config) of an Rviz plugin? Thank you very much for your time.

- Chris

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-10-12**:
Every plugin can persist information through these two callbacks: https://github.com/ros-visualization/qt_gui_core/blob/1eaff5a7586e78ec4f5bf501d9a3172a5da07b06/qt_gui/src/qt_gui/plugin.py#L50-L68

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-10-12**:
The `rqt_rviz` plugin would need to implement those order to store / restore information.

**Comment by [cshannon](https://answers.ros.org/users/24410/cshannon/) on 2015-10-12**:
Thank you!

**Comment by [cshannon](https://answers.ros.org/users/24410/cshannon/) on 2015-11-01**:
Hi Dirk, can you please let me know the file/file location in which to place the two callbacks for the rqt_rviz plugin? I'm not finding an rviz.cpp file. Thanks again.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2015-11-01**:
https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_robot_plugins/blob/master/rqt_rviz/src/rqt_rviz/rviz.cpp

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-16**:
Where does it save the default perspective? I can't seem to find it. But it does save it for sure because restarting rqt returns to the state it was exited in.

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2016-08-17**:
@2ROS0 http://answers.ros.org/question/53721/set-rqt_gui-perspectives-from-command-line/?answer=53746#post-id-53746

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can import and export perspectives via the *Perspective* menu.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-06-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2016-08-16**:
Where does it save the default perspective? I can't seem to find it. But it does save it for sure because restarting rqt returns to the state it was exited in.

**Comment by [Arthur Queiroz](https://answers.ros.org/users/23076/arthur-queiroz/) on 2017-03-17**:
Is there any reason for the the difference between in saving configuration in RVIZ and saving perspectives in RQT? RVIZ remembers which config file it was opened with and I can just ctrl-s to update it. On rqt, I need to export the perspective, selecting the file path again every time I do it.

**Comment by [dogh](https://answers.ros.org/users/41851/dogh/) on 2019-06-14**:
Storing perspective is kind of unuseful as it does not store all the configuration made

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-07-29**:
Each plugin is responsible to store/restore its intrinsic state and most plugins do that correctly. If a specific plugin doesn't do that for you you might want to fill a ticket in the repository containing that rqt plugin.